# java if statement not executing

Tags: java

I am relatively new to java and this is my first time working with if else statements.  I was attempting to make a basic game in which the user guesses a number between 1-3, and the program tells them if they are right or wrong.  However, when I go to execute the program, when I type 1, the program does not respond and I have to use ctrl-E to end it.  What am I doing wrong?  When I enter values aside from 1, the program executes as I want it to by printing "Goodbye."

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GuessTheNumber {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner game = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        System.out.println("Hey there!  Want to play a game?");
        System.out.println("\tIf yes, type 1");
        System.out.println("\tIf no, type 2");
        int ans1 = game.nextInt();

        if (ans1 == 1) {  // This is true, yet when I type 1, nothing happens.
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt((3 - 1) + 1) + 1;
            int guess = game.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Great!  I am thinking of an integer between 1     and 3.  Guess what it is?");

            if (guess == randomNum) {
                System.out.println("Congradulations!  You guessed correctly!  The number was" + randomNum);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, your guess was incorrect.  The number I was thinking of was" + randomNum);
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("Goodbye.");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first time posting here, so I apologize if this question has been answered elsewhere.

Comment: So you write a program which expects another input after the first "1" and then you wonder why it does so?

Answer (score 0):

Because if ans1=1, then it expects another input from user and checks if the guess and another input are same.

This is second input that it is waiting for

```
     int guess = game.nextInt();
```

Input any number ,if the random number generated is equal to the number you added second time, it will return "Congradulations!  You guessed correctly!  The number was" else "Sorry, your guess was incorrect.  The number I was thinking of was" with number

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
int guess = game.nextInt();
System.out.println( "Great!  I am thinking of an integer between 1     and 3.  Guess what it is?" );
```

You should have them reversed.

```
System.out.println( "Great!  I am thinking of an integer between 1     and 3.  Guess what it is?" );
int guess = game.nextInt();
```